# How to detect inclined lines in an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i have a question regarding line detection. I have an image (in fact edge image/ edge map) containing some horizontal, some vertical and some inclined lines. I want to find only inclined lines from that image. How can i do that by searching the entire edge map, as i don't have any information about these lines? I have to search the entire map to search the coordinates (or any other related information). Now can any one help me out how to do that?

Thanks alot

Comment: I think cv::HoughLinesP http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_feature_detection.html#index-8169  is a good starting point

Comment: look through these SO questions to get an idea: [tag:MATLAB hough](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[matlab]+hough)

Comment: Thanks alot for all of you guys for contributing to solve my problem :)

Comment: [This](http://www.cvmt.dk/education/teaching/e07/MED3/IP/Carsten_Hoilund_-_Radon_Transform.pdf) is a good document I found on estimation of angles at which lines are present in an image using Radon Transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first thought i have about this problem is only a varient the way to use the hough transform because you can analize the acumulator of hough transform, in this acumulator you have the angle and rho of every line detected you can define that only you care the line that have a angle diferent to 0 and 90

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/amos/hough.html

http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~hamarneh/ecopy/compvis1999_hough.pdf

Is the best way i can imagine  because you have the angle of each line

Comment: Thanks, although i didn't implemented but it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a maths question really. What you want is a Radon transform: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to write a sphere detection algorithm, which was also based on edge detection. You state that you know nothing about the inclined lines. This is problematic. You could for example filter out whatever edge points belong to staight lines and then use an algorithm to group the points which belong to inclined lines. You could then use linear equations to find the characteristics of the inclined lines.

Hope it helped.

Comment: to detect vertical lines i just start searching my edge map vertically and start searching for the white pixel and from first detected white pixel i continue till the last white pixel and then the first pixel become the starting point of the line and last pixel become the end point of that line. So in that way i found all vertical lines and for horizontal i search the edge map horizontally. hope this make sense
Now i am not able to find a technique to search the edge map to detect inclined lines. Could you now please guide me how to do that? M just looking for a technique to implement my algo

Comment: As I said you can discard the vertical and horizontal lines. Then you will be left with the pixels which belong to the inclined lines. Then next step would be to cluster those points together. How would you do that? Well sine they are lines you could starts by searching for adjacent pixels which do not belong to a vertical or horizontal line. You should impose some limits, for example search in a radius of 1 pixel or 0.5 pixels. If you find a matching pixel you could then start forming a line and from the edges of that line try to extend it until there are no more "alone" pixels left.

Comment: How can i differentiate either the pixel belongs to the vertical, horizontal or inclined line?

Comment: Say you got pixel a. Search adjacent pixels and try to form an inclined line. If pixel a +- 1 vertically and horizontally are other white pixels then they belong to a vertical and horizontal line (I guess). Do your lines correlate? Or are they randomly placed?

Comment: They are random.
Thanx alot for all your replies..
I got the solution.. its very simple;)
Simply after getting 1st white pixel, increment both x and y coordinates if got next white pixel increment again and so on till got last white pixel.. if not then decrement 1st coordinate say 'x' and increment second say 'y' and if got white pixel continue decreasing x and increasing y coordinate till last white pixel.. (do this to detect both left and right sloped lines)... or otherwise simply ignore that white pixel cz it will not belong to any line..
Any other g0od idea will be appreciated, as its slow

Comment: The problem is that if you don't know anything about the inclined lines you will "have" to scan the entire image slowly. If you know for example the inclination factor you could map the points to matrices and then solve a linear equation system. The points that would be valid according to the system they would of course belong to the inclined lines.